# Mocking Request Header module using Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs, fetch-api, es6-modules, request-headers

```
function createRequest(method) {
     const init = {
         method,
         headers: new Headers({.....}),
     };

    return new Request(url, init); }
```

I am using Request headers (with Fetch) in the above code (https://davidwalsh.name/fetch )

However while writing unit test cases using Jest, it gives me this error:   ReferenceError: Headers is not defined

DO I need to mock even these standard modules? How should I import Headers in unit test cases

Comment: I am having same issue. Have you managed to fix this?

Answer (score 7):

I say yes, mocking **Headers** is definitely an option in a testing context.
In my particular case, I have simply mocked it like so:

```
global.Headers = ()=>{}
```

This will work just fine if you want to test that your code is behaving properly based on the response returned by fetch.
If you also need to check that the correct headers are sent, you would need a more sophisticated mock, and/or perhaps a specialized test suite for your networking methods.

Comment: Works fine, but I need a method `append()` in the Headers object (it is used in code actively), how can I set it there?

Comment: @ArthurKushman You could return an object with the definition of **append**: `global.Headers = ()=>{ append:()=>{} }`

Comment: it was the 1st thing I've tried to do and the error is: TypeError: headers.append is not a function, code: `global.Headers = () => {
            append:() => {}
        }` also tried to set 2 arguments to append - nothing helped. The ability to test Headers with it's methods is crucial for my app, it would be great to have such an ability.

Comment: @ArthurKushman Of course this will not work as your code expects **Headers** to have a constructor, my bad. Have a look at the Jest documentation about [Class mocks](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/es6-class-mocks.html), it should answer your question.

Comment: Did you find the working code? I am also stuck in this.

Answer (score 4):

adding ' import "isomorphic-fetch" ' to the jest setup file should resolve this issue as this will make the missing dom APIs available in the tests

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but for anyone who runs into this (as I did), this worked for me:

```
// before running each test
beforeEach(() => {
  // define `append` as a mocked fn
  const append = jest.fn();
  // set test `Headers`
  global.Headers = () => ({
    append: append,
  });
});
```